# Optimizing MySQL query when "or" is used

Tags: mysql

The two tables contain over 1m records.

This query takes 15 seconds to run and returns 1 record (correct):

```
    select orders.*
        from orders
    left join orders_details on orders.orderID=orders_details.orderID
        where 
orders_details.trackingRef='GYD41624' 
or orders.orderID = (
select distinct  orderID from orders_rebookings
 where trackingRef='GYD41624'
)   
    group by orders.orderID
```

Whereas if I run the query with each of the where conditions separately then each is very quick:

This takes 0.0015 seconds (1 match found):

```
select orders.*
    from orders
left join orders_details on orders.orderID=orders_details.orderID
    where orders.orderID = (select distinct orderID from orders_rebookings where trackingRef='GYD41624')    
group by orders.orderID
```

And this takes almost no time and finds no matches (this is correct):

```
select orders.*
    from orders
left join orders_details on orders.orderID=orders_details.orderID
    where orders_details.trackingRef='GYD41624'     
group by orders.orderID
```

So if I have two very quick queries, how can I make the first one containing the "or" almost as fast?

Comment: - replace the distinct from inside the subquery with a group by

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union` or `union all` to combine them:

```
select o.*
from orders o left join
    orders_details od
    on o.orderID = od.orderID
where o.orderID = (select distinct orderID from orders_rebookings where trackingRef = 'GYD41624')    
group by o.orderID
union
select o.*
from orders o left join
     orders_details od
     on o.orderID = od.orderID
where od.trackingRef = 'GYD41624'     
group by o.orderID;
```

`union` is slightly less efficient, because it removes duplicates.

Your query is also dangerous, because it has `= (select . . .)`.  If the subquery returns more than one row, you will get an error.

I wonder if this form would perform better:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where exists (select 1 from orders_details where o.orderID = od.orderID and od.trackingRef = 'GYD41624') or
      exists (select 1 from orders_rebookings orr where o.orderID = orr.orderID and orr.trackingRef = 'GYD41624')
```

You would want the appropriate indexes (`orders_details(orderId, TrackingRef)` and `orders_rebookings(orderId, trackingRef)`).

Comment: Hi. Good idea, I hadn't considered this. My problem here is that the issue I am having is actually contained within a much larger query. I just isolated out this bit to make the example clear. I may be able to apply the union concept back to the large query but I was hoping for something quite simple :-)